# start windows console app parameters

Tags: batch-file, console-application

what parameters should i use to start a console app minimized or hidden?

is this possible without using a 3rd party program?

with a batch file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
start /min c:\windows\cmd.exe
```

Then you can pass whatever parameters to cmd.exe you need, for example:

To process a command then close:

```
start /min c:\windows\cmd.exe /c dir
```

To process a command but stay open:

```
start /min c:\windows\cmd.exe /k dir
```